# I accidentally used a bathroom sponge on my dishes

Tags: food-safety, kitchen

Somebody help, please! I don’t know what to do?

Comment: Wash it again with a clean sponge? What have you used that sponge on before? just tiles, sink or toilet bowl? That might make a difference.

Answer (score 6):

I mean, I wouldn't eat off them like that. I suggest washing them with regular dishwashing equipment first.

Your dishes aren't ruined or anything. A big reason they're made out of something non-porous, like ceramic or metal or plastic, is so you can scrub them clean with soap and water without any food or, uh, other stuff getting stuck inside them. The scrubbing clears off any macroscopic dirt, and the soap both rinses off microscopic stuff and kills a lot of microorganisms. If cleaning dishes with normal methods weren't enough to get rid of dangerous germs, a whole lot more people would get food poisoning.

Comment: Maybe he needs some special cleaning method but not just regular dish-washing equipment. Seems he might have some "shadows" on the dishes...

Comment: What do you mean by "shadows"? The ghost of poop?

Comment: Fears, more precisely.

Comment: I don't think there are chemicals to get rid of that. ;-)

Comment: @Sneftel - oh but there are ... just not the type you put in your dishwater ... ;)

Comment: I once read a post where someone freaked out because someone else washed their underwear with their other clothes. When health inspectors came to my restaurants, they would mark you down for using sponges cause they could harbor bacteria. In this case, the greatest fear is the fear itself--knowing what has occurred rather than any real danger but, I agree, rewashing them should rinse those fears down the drain.

Answer (score -1):

If your dishes are ceramic, you could put them into a pot, fill in water and heat up until boiling and switch the fire off. Later turn cooler take them out, then use 70% rubbing alcohol to wipe your dishes, then finally wash them with clean water thoroughly.

Any regular or special cleaning method should do the work to get rid of those dirtiness or adhered bacteria. However if you still have concern about the dishes, maybe just abandon or not use them and remember to separate bathroom's and kitchen's sponges completely, and DO NOT misuse again. Prevention is always better than a cure.

Comment: Is that how you ordinarily wash your dishes? What special things do you expect rubbing alcohol to do?

Comment: @Sneftel Of course not. Due to his dishes is contaminated with bathroom sponge(maybe the sponge is used to wipe the toliet? I don't know), alcohol might be not too heavy for cleaning because those dishes still need to put food on it!

Comment: @Sneftel 70% alcohol is often used in labs as a surface decontaminant as it is pretty good a killing bacteria and viruses through dehydration, destruction of lipid membranes and precipitation of proteins. 100% doesn't work so well, it's too quick to evaporate and more expensive to use.